# Proof that a complex number raised to a complex power is complex.

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to justify the euler formula to myself namely why:
$$e^{ix}=\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$
And  I thought that the Second derivative of 
$$e^{ix}$$,
Is normal to its first derivative,since one is purely imaginary an another is purely real.
So it maps a circle.and the RHS is just the polar form  of the circle,
QED.
BUT:I realized I had assumed that $$e^{ix}$$
Is complex,meaning where$ a,b \in \mathbb R$ Such that $$e^{ix}=a+bi$$
I'm stuck proving this to be true.

ADDED:the question ,(as said in the title) was about how to justify that $$e^{ix}$$ is a complex number.

Comment: It's not ture, if $x=0$ it's simply $1$ which is real

Comment: A complex number contains the reals.  I think you thought of imaginary numbers which are only in the form $ai$.  But a complex number can be real if its imaginary part is equal to zero.

Comment: What you're trying to prove boils down to check that the complex exponential is well defined.

Comment: How do i go about doing that?

Comment: To the statement in the title, what about $i^i$?

Comment: Indeed, this is a question in search of (at least) one (and possibly several) definition(s) before making sense.

Comment: I think if we use the euler formula itself,this should be pretty straight forward:$ i^i = e^{\ln(i^i)} =e^{i\ln(i)} $ so we substitute $x = \ln(i)$ in the eulers formula.

Comment: Which moves the problem to know what is $\log z$ for $z$ complex.

Comment: One can easily show by euler's formula that for any complex number $z$: $$Ce^{i\theta} = z$$ and taking the $\ln $of both sides:$$\ln(z) = \ln(C)+i\theta$$

Comment: @LoganLuther "Easily" is a fig leaf for undefined notions here, I am afraid. But since I discovered your comment by chance (ever heard of @?) and since you seem to be attached to whatever false notions you may have about complex logarithms, it might be best to leave the matter as it is.

Comment: @Did my knowledge of the matter is purely geometric,and not based on the foundations of complex analysis,(no one teaches this subject in senior year of my highschool with the level of rigour that exists in analysis.(especially in my country,iran!,).and even the question in a way states that this question is a kind of a intuition based one,("Justify to myself..."), and I would really appreciate any clarification done with regards to my mistakes and gaps.And  no I didn't know about @

Comment: Your main mistake is that theta in your previous comment is not uniquely defined.

Comment: @DidI meant the$ arg(z)$,the angle it makes with the real axis. I saw this as conventional notation for the $arg(z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous different definitions of the complex exponential; one can check that they give the same values, etc.

For starters, you can invert Euler's formula and simply *define* $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$.  It's clear that this is a well-defined function for all real $x$ (as long as you accept that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are well-defined for all real values), and then one can use trigonometry as well as the definition of complex multiplication to show that $e^{i(x+y)}=e^{ix}e^{iy}$, as well as the various other properties of the exponential function (for instance, that it still satisfies the differential equation $\frac{d}{dx}e^{cx}=ce^{cx}$).

Alternately, you can - as suggested - define $e^z$ for all $z$, real or complex, via the power series $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!}$.  Then you have to show convergence (which follows the usual argument: just use the ratio test and show that the ratio of terms goes to zero for all $z$, so it's certainly bounded below $1$), and once you have convergence, you can use the usual formulas (as well as absolute convergence) to show that the usual rules for the exponential, as well as Euler's formula, fall out of this definition.

But note that all of these are *definitions*; we can say with surety that $e^z$ is a complex number because we've *specified* what (complex) number it is, in each of these definitions.

Comment: Interesting.but this begs the question:which way of defining this defintion is cleaner/better? Which one is more useful?

Comment: @LoganLuther All of the above, and none of the above, and more besides.  (For instance, one can even _define_ the exponential function $e()$ as the solution of the differential equation $\frac{de(x)}{dx}=e(x)$, then show that it has the given power series, that the series converges, etc.) Each of these constructions has its merits and its drawbacks, making some things easier and others a little more difficult, and providing different perspectives on the exponential. But they all come to the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked the calculus argument: consider the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ defined by $$f(x) = e^{-ix}(\cos(x) + i \sin(x)), \,\,\,\, x \in \mathbb R.$$ Then by the product rule \begin{align*}f'(x) &= -ie^{-ix}(\cos(x) + i \sin(x)) + e^{-ix}(-\sin x + i\cos(x)) \\ 
&= e^{-ix}(-i \cos(x) + \sin(x))+ e^{-ix}(-\sin x + i\cos(x)) \\
&= e^{-ix}(-i \cos(x) + \sin(x)-\sin x + i\cos(x)) = 0, \,\,\,\, x \in \mathbb R.
\end{align*} Thus $f$ is a constant function. It is clear that $f(0) = 1$ so we must have $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. That is, for any $x \in \mathbb R$, $$e^{-ix}(\cos(x) + i \sin(x)) = 1 \,\,\,\, \Longleftrightarrow \,\,\,\,\, \cos(x) + i\sin(x) = e^{ix}.$$

Comment: I see where this is going,but it's not simply what I have asked for,which is why $e^{ix}$ is a complex number.

Comment: @LoganLuther "I see where this is going,but it's not simply what I have asked for" Then why accept this post as "the" answer, some mere 2 hours after it is posted?

Comment: I mistakenly clicked on this instead of steven  stadnicki's answer. It should be fixed now...

Answer (score 0):

I think the most 'honest' approach is using power series, especially if your 'honest' definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is in terms of power series. Euler's formula follows immediately.

Comment: I know how to prove the equation using power series,and the proof is not my problem.please read the title of the question.